# Why use selenium instead of chromedriver standalone?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm a little new to e2e testing and was wondering why someone would choose to use Selenium to run Chrome (via chromedriver) instead of just using chromedriver by itself?

I'm using NightwatchJS and wondering about the different setups

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a poke at this and say it is because Chromedriver needs Selenium Webdriver to run. Think of Chromedriver as an extension of Webdriver.

Comment: I mean, I can setup nightwatch js to use the standalone chromedriver, minus selenium